# Why does .exe built using pyinstaller isn't working?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "eel\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "bottle.py", line 73, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

here's the pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon icon.ico --name "Useful Tools for Windows" --uac-admin --add-data "web;web/" main.py
```

here's the source code:

```py
# Imports system commands
import os

# Imports eel, a Electron like GUI for Python.
import eel

eel.init("web")

# Fixes Chrome not installed.
eel.browsers.set_path(
    "chrome", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
)


@eel.expose
def openHosts():
    os.system(
        "attrib -r %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts && start notepad.exe %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
    )


@eel.expose
def openOfficeAddins():
    os.system("explorer.exe %AppData%\Microsoft\AddIns")


@eel.expose
def openCurrentUserStartMenu():
    os.system("explorer.exe %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu")


@eel.expose
def openAllUserStartMenu():
    os.system("explorer.exe C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu")


@eel.expose
def openSentTo():
    os.system("explorer.exe %Appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo")


@eel.expose
def openCurrentUserStartup():
    os.system("explorer.exe %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")


@eel.expose
def openAllUsersStartup():
    os.system(
        "explorer.exe C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"
    )


@eel.expose
def openWordStartup():
    os.system("explorer.exe %AppData%\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP")


@eel.expose
def openPSReadLineHistory():
    os.system(
        "notepad %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\ConsoleHost_history.txt"
    )


@eel.expose
def installYouTubeDownloader():
    os.system("winget install MoheshwarAmarnathBiswas.YouTubeVideoDownloader")


@eel.expose
def installPowerToys():
    os.system("winget install Microsoft.PowerToys")


@eel.expose
def installSysInternals():
    os.system("winget install --id 9P7KNL5RWT25")


@eel.expose
def openAccountPictures():
    os.system("explorer shell:AccountPictures")


@eel.expose
def openFolderOptions():
    os.system("explorer shell:::{6DFD7C5C-2451-11d3-A299-00C04F8EF6AF}")


@eel.expose
def openInternetOptions():
    os.system("explorer shell:::{A3DD4F92-658A-410F-84FD-6FBBBEF2FFFE}")


@eel.expose
def openSoundOptions():
    os.system("explorer shell:::{F2DDFC82-8F12-4CDD-B7DC-D4FE1425AA4D}")


@eel.expose
def openPowerOptions():
    os.system("explorer shell:::{025A5937-A6BE-4686-A844-36FE4BEC8B6D}")


@eel.expose
def openOptionalFeatures():
    os.system("start %WINDIR%\System32\OptionalFeatures.exe")


@eel.expose
def openControlPanel():
    os.system("start control.exe")


@eel.expose
def wsreset():
    os.system("start wsreset.exe")


@eel.expose
def wureset():
    os.system("net stop bits")
    os.system("net stop wuauserv")
    os.system("net stop CryptSvc")
    os.system("net stop msiserver")
    os.system("del %windir%\SoftwareDistribution")
    os.system("del %windir%\system32\catroot2")
    os.system("net start bits")
    os.system("net start wuauserv")
    os.system("net start CryptSvc")
    os.system("net start msiserver")


@eel.expose
def openGodMode():
    os.system("explorer.exe shell:::{ed7ba470-8e54-465e-825c-99712043e01c}")


eel.start("index.html")
```

Full source code: https://github.com/fluentmoheshwar/useful-tools

Dependencies used:

```
altgraph==0.17.3
black==22.12.0
bottle==0.12.23
bottle-websocket==0.2.9
cffi==1.15.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
Eel==0.15.1
future==0.18.3
gevent==22.10.2
gevent-websocket==0.10.1
greenlet==2.0.1
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
pathspec==0.10.3
pefile==2022.5.30
platformdirs==2.6.2
pycparser==2.21
pyinstaller==5.7.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2022.15
pyparsing==3.0.9
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
tomli==2.0.1
whichcraft==0.6.1
zope.event==4.6
zope.interface==5.5.2
```

Using Microsoft Store version of Python: Yes.
Using venv: yes.

I tried installing wheel and reinstalling dependencies.
I tried adding `C:\Windows\System32\downlevel` to path.
I tried recreating venv.

Comment: You could try to create a [example]. Your code is still not minimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the libraries you are using is attempting to write to `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`, which are set to `None` when you run pyinstaller with the `-w` `--windowed` or `--noconsole` options.

You need to explicitly set `sys.stderr` and `sys.stdout` in your programs code as early as possible to a writeable object like an open file or an io buffer.

for example:

```
import sys, io

buffer = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = buffer
```