# Pyinstaller --noconsole

Tags: pyinstaller

When I convert the code:

```py
from yfinance import download
result = download(['GM', 'F'], start = '2022-01-01', end = '2022-12-31')
```

to an executable via

```
pyinstaller [name].py
```

it works fine. However, if I try to remove the console via

```
pyinstaller --noconsole [name].py
```

I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "[name].py", line 10, in    File "yfinance\multi.py", line 145, in download   File "yfinance\utils.py", line 773, in completed AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'flush'

I could live with the console showing up, but it's a bit annoying and I would prefer to fix the issue. I'm running the development version of Pyinstaller. It was installed via

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does .exe built using pyinstaller isn't working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75232011/why-does-exe-built-using-pyinstaller-isnt-working)  Not the same question but the answer should solve your issue as well.

Comment: Don't forget to vote the answer up if it helped.