# Unhandled exception in script error when converting py to exe file

Tags: exception, pyinstaller, attributeerror, unhandled

I have a problem in converting py to exe file by pyinstaller as the below error comes

```
unhandled exception in script.
Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception: None type object has no attribute 'write'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "pip\__init__.py", line 13, in main
  File "pip\_internal\utils\entrypoints.py", line 35, in _wrapper
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv1cw.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does .exe built using pyinstaller isn't working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75232011/why-does-exe-built-using-pyinstaller-isnt-working)