# Python docx2pdf cannot convert docx to pdf when bundled with pyinstaller

Tags: python, user-interface, pyinstaller, python-docx, docx2pdf

I am using Customtkinter to build GUI which reads data from an excel file, then creates a word document with this file, converts it to pdf and encrypts it. I am using the **python-docx** module to write the word document, then the convert function of the **docx2pdf** module to **convert** the docx file to pdf. This works very well when the code is run in PyCharm or Jupyter Notebook. When the code is bundled with **pyinstaller** as an exe, this function does not work and the error produced from the log file is

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'`

The code block for this part of the GUI is below

```
## this function has been defined at the top of the script
def get_script_directory():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))

## some relevant modules imported
from datetime import datetime
from docx2pdf import convert
from docx import Document
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
from docx.oxml.shared import OxmlElement
from docx.shared import Inches, Pt
from pikepdf import Pdf, Encryption
from spire.doc import Document as spiredoc, FileFormat
from tkinter import messagebox

import docx, io, sys

## portion of code to generate pdf from word document
folder = fr'\{month.title()} {year} Payslips'

doc.save(get_script_directory() + fr"{folder}\{name} {month} {year} Payslip.docx")
try:
    convert(get_script_directory() + fr"{folder}\{name} {month} {year} Payslip.docx",
            get_script_directory() + fr"{folder}\{name} {month} {year} Payslip.pdf")
except Exception as Argument:
    logging.warning(f'{datetime.now()}: {Argument}')
    raise
file_name = get_script_directory() + fr"{folder}\{name} {month} {year} Payslip.pdf"
pdf = Pdf.open(file_name)
try:
    password = str(staff_details.loc[name, 'PASSWORDS'])
except:
    password = name.title().split()[0].casefold()
pdf.save(get_script_directory() + fr"\{folder}\{name} {month} {year} Encrypted Payslip.pdf",
         encryption=Encryption(owner=password, user=password, R=4))
pdf.close()
```

I changed to the **aspose** and the **spire.doc** modules but I get the error

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Document_CreateDocument'`.

Also those put watermarks on the pdf. I would like to avoid these as much as possible and only use them as a last resort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does .exe built using pyinstaller isn't working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75232011/why-does-exe-built-using-pyinstaller-isnt-working)

Comment: @Alexander, thanks for sharing this. I think this pretty much explains why the error is occurring. However, on implementing the solution the error does not pop up, but the PDF is still not created even in PyCharm. Also, with the one I shared, the Word document was created but with this solution, that is not created either.

Comment: then you need to create a [mre]